# Splitting a File List by delimiter into 2 Arrays with Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm having trouble splitting this into 2 arrays with a shell script: Teams and Indexes

I need to turn this:

```
dma_ref_team:team_id
dma_ref_department:department_id
```

Into 1 array `${tables}` with `(dma_ref_team, dma_ref_department)`
and 1 array `${indices}` with `(team_id, department_id)`

I can assign any delimiter and format the file however I want so any suggestions there could help as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? `mapfile` is a bash4+ feature jfyi.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t array < file.txt

tables=("${array[@]%:*}")
indices=("${array[@]#*:}")

printf '%s\n' "${tables[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${indices[@]}"
```

Comment: this worked thanks! - passed it into fileItemString=$(cat /table_list.txt |tr "\n" " ") instead of mapfile and still parsed it

Comment: Glad I could help, well good luck with your project. Although `tr '\n' ' ' < /table_list.txt` should work too, without the `cat` and the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to store directly into each array with an index.

```
$ i=0; while IFS=: read table[i] indices[i]; do let i++; done < myfile
```